# Extend events of Infragistics WebDropDown

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I'm intending to attach my custom handler to the "DropDownClosing" event of WebDropDown.

I tried the below for a sample.

```
$IG.WebDropDown.prototype = {
    openDropDown: function () { alert(1); }
}
```

But it throws error while being parsed by DOM (Uncaught ReferenceError: $IG is not defined).

Interestingly, the below one works but it shows the alert and skips all other native functionality. (e.g After alert the dropdown is not opening)

```
$IG.WebDropDown.prototype.openDropDown = function () { alert(1); }
```

The goal is, all the webdropdowns in my application should use my customer function and I want to configure this at one place rather than adding the "DropDownClosing" client event for every webdropdown.

What is the right approach to extend an event of a control in infragistics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same client event handler for all `WebDropDowns` on the page, but you still have to tell each to subscribe to this handler and to use it:

```
<ig:WebDropDown ID="myDropDown1" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents DropDownClosing="dropDownClosing" />
</ig:WebDropDown>

<ig:WebDropDown ID="myDropDown2" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents DropDownClosing="dropDownClosing" />
</ig:WebDropDown>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dropDownClosing(sender, eventArgs) {
    alert(1);
}
</script>
```

What you've tried is an override of the `WebDropDown` `openDropDown` client method. This will override the opening functionality for the control, and thus the drop down wouldn't open, unless you re-implement the functionality yourself, or use a cached reference to the original implementation. This is not the same as attaching an event handler.